# Show Notifications for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I just built a simple chrome extension to show tweets for a particular key word. It works fine. Every time a new tweet is available if the user clicks on the extension icon it shows up.

But is there a way to show some notification in the extension icon to indicate that new data is retrieved?

Here is my javascript code

```
var req=null;
window.onload = function() {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=20SongsThatILike", true);
    req.onload = showTweets;
    req.send(null);
}

function showTweets() {
    var title=req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('title')[1].childNodes[0];
    var author=req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('author')[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];

    document.body.appendChild(title);
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://search.twitter.com/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. But [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i have updated my code above

Comment: Yes, through [long polling or sockets](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). I suggest you give it a try and if you have any problems implementing that, ask again.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '<number_of_new_teets>'});
```

this code will put a number on icon of y